# disable on click of Radiobutton

Tags: javascript

Disable When Radio button click let us consider the example Main Group ,Country other to be disable the textbox for zone,city,state,area manager,like wise if i select Main Group,Zone..then country,city,state,area manager have to be disable...??? like wise it go...

```
<script language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript">
    function fun(s)
    {
        /* table 1 */
        var A=document.getElementById("maingroups").value;
        var B=document.getElementById("subgroups").value;
        var C=document.getElementById("itemnames").value;

        /* table 2 */

         var a=document.getElementById("countrys").value;
         var b=document.getElementById("zones").value;
         var c=document.getElementById("states").value;
         var d=document.getElementById("citys").value;
         var e=document.getElementById("Areamanagers").value;
         var f=document.getElementById("outlets").value;


         /* table 1 */

         if(s==A)
          {

          document.getElementById("maingroup").style.display='';
          document.getElementById("subgroup").style.display='none';
          document.getElementById("itemname").style.display='none';


          }

         if(s==B)
        {
              document.getElementById("maingroup").style.display='none';
              document.getElementById("subgroup").style.display='';
              document.getElementById("itemname").style.display='none';

          }

         if(s==C)
        {
             document.getElementById("maingroup").style.display='none';
             document.getElementById("subgroup").style.display='none';
             document.getElementById("itemname").style.display='';


          }





    </script>
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/KjX3H/1/) 
for reference

Comment: Please provide minimal code that describes your problem, and possibly a fiddle. Thanks

Comment: Are you want to disable the Sub Group and Item Name if Main Group is clicked

Comment: this code is so hardcoded, can you name the variables just a little intuitive? variables like a,b,c,d,e,f are totally poor

Comment: no sir if i select main group,country other textbox to be disable like-wise for if select main group,zone other to be disable...

Comment: i update the link can u some body look on it...

Comment: @user3032277 check my answer and demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your html and script like this:

## Srcipt

```
 window.onload = function () {
        //hide all text inputs
        var allTextInputs = textFileds.querySelectorAll('input[type = "text"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < allTextInputs.length; i++) {
            allTextInputs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

        //based on radio value and name enables text
        var allRadioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="A"],input[type="radio"][name="B"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < allRadioInputs.length; i++) {
            allRadioInputs[i].onclick = function () {
                var name = this.getAttribute('name');

                var value = this.value;
                switch (name) {
                    case 'A': {
                        var mainTextInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"].main');
                        for (i = 0; i < mainTextInputs.length; i++) {
                            mainTextInputs[i].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                        document.getElementById(value).style.display = 'inline';
                        document.getElementById(value).setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'B': {
                        var subTextInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"].sub');
                        for (i = 0; i < subTextInputs.length; i++) {
                            subTextInputs[i].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                        document.getElementById(value).style.display = 'inline';
                        document.getElementById(value).setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                        break;
                    }
                    default: break;
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

## Html

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="2" bgcolor="pink">
<tr id="main">
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="A" id="maingroups" value="maingroup"></td>
    <td><font size="2">Main Group</font></td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="A" id="subgroups" value="subgroup"></td>
    <td><font size="2">Sub Group</font></td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="A" id="itemnames" value="itemname"></td>
    <td><font size="2">Item Name</font></td>
</tr>

<tr id="sub">
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="B" id="countrys" value="country"></td>
    <td><font size="2">Country</font></td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="B" id="zones" value="zone"></td>
    <td><font size="2">Zone</font></td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="B" id="states" value="state"></td>
    <td><font size="2">State</font></td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="B" id="citys" value="city"></td>
    <td><font size="2">City</font></td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="B" id="Areamanagers" value="Areamanager"></td>
    <td><font size="2">Area Manager</font></td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="B" id="outlets" value="outlet"></td>
    <td><font size="2">Outlet</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="textFileds">
<input type="text" name="maingroup" id="maingroup" class="main" value="A" />    
<input type="text" name="subgroup" id="subgroup" class="main" value="B" />    
<input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname" class="main" value="C" />    
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="sub" value="D" />    
<input type="text" name="zone" id="zone" class="sub" value="E" />    
<input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="sub" value="F" />    
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="sub" value="G" />    
<input type="text" name="Areamanager" id="Areamanager" class="sub" value="H" />    
<input type="text" name="outlet" id="outlet" class="sub" value="I" />

<input type="submit" name="ab" value="Run Report" />
</div>
```

**Here is the** <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMLts/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: @user3032277 what do you mean by that?

Comment: You will select radio button for Main Group first and then the Zone right? then what?

Comment: let us consider that am having two section (i.e)first row and second..row.so user can select by Main Group is one option and other one may be country or zone,state...etc...or else  Sub Group is one option and other one may be country or zone,state...etc ...so now my requirement is  if user select Main Group ,country other of second row like zone,state,city of textbox to be disable at the time when i move to Main Group,zone other  of second row like country,state,city of textbox to be disable not radio button

Comment: Your setting the textboxes display to none on the body onload, and you want to disable the textboxes that visble on clikcing the corresponding radio.

Comment: You dont want to disable the radio buttons, do you?

Comment: yes i don’t want disable radio button..... based on selection other to be disable the text box only that’s it....

Comment: @user3032277 one suggestion if your just want to disable the textbox then you can simple set the disable attribute into the html like `<input type="text" name="maingroup" id="maingroup" class="main" value="A" disabled="disabled" />`

Comment: but  user can select any radio button...then how its possible to disable like.this...